# Only variable should be passed by referenced in Magento problem

Tags: php, debugging, magento

In order to see the path to template in generated html source code for debuggin purposes I used the following code snippet in the

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php

```
/**
 * Render block
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function renderView()
{
    $this->setScriptPath(Mage::getBaseDir('design'));
    $showDebug = true;
    if (!$showDebug) {
        $html = $this->fetchView($this->getTemplateFile());
    }
    else {
        $template = $this->getTemplateFile();
        $tagName = 'template_'.current(explode('.',end(explode('/',$template))));
        $html = '<'.$tagName.'><!-- '.$template.' -->';
        $html .= $this->fetchView($template);
        $html .= '<!--/ '.$template.' --></'.$tagName.'>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

but now in the error logs I see the following:
2010-12-13T21:55:35+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 245

How should this be referenced in order to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure your problem is this line

```
$tagName = 'template_'.current(explode('.',end(explode('/',$template))));
```

The [end](https://www.php.net/end) and [current](https://www.php.net/current) methods accept an array variable as a paramater, passed by reference.   You're passing the result of a function call, which PHP doesn't like.  Assuming that snippet is trying to get an extension-less template name, try this instead

```
$parts  = pathinfo($template);
$tagName    = $parts['filename'];
```

Comment: @Alan This works. And the error is gone. When you say assuming the snippet is trying to get an extension-less template name I don't quite follow what you mean.

Comment: A template name: "foo/baz/bar.html".  A template name: "bar.html".  An extension-less template name: "bar"

Comment: Only problem is this methods causes some parts of admin to display in correctly such editing a cms page

Comment: @capnhud: When you use a feature in a part of a system where it wasn't designed to be used, things like that will happen.

Comment: Well in lue of template hints is there another way to do this to obtain similar results?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Developer Toolbar extension instead.  Or turn on Template Hints from the Admin.

Comment: The benefit of this snippet is that it allows you to look at the generated html and see exactly what template is being called, whereas the template hints shows an overlay, but then you need to keep the page open in order to refer back to the template in question.